# Java Logging - Is there a way to control what data be inserted into the xml?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I was learning about java logging mechanism and I wrote the following code.The following code logs the 2 messages in a file named `LOGGED.xml`.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.io.IOException;

class Tester {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName());
    FileHandler fHandler = new FileHandler("LOGGED.xml");
    logger.addHandler(fHandler);
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"This is an info log message");
    logger.log(Level.WARNING,"This is a warning message");
    fHandler.close();
  }
}
```

Following is what I see in the *xml* file :

```
<log>
 <record>
  <date>2013-02-02T16:42:48</date>
  <millis>1359803568992</millis>
  <sequence>0</sequence>
  <logger>Tester</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>Tester</class>
  <method>main</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>This is an info log message</message>
 </record>

 <record>
  <date>2013-02-02T16:42:49</date>
  <millis>1359803569031</millis>
  <sequence>1</sequence>
  <logger>Tester</logger>
  <level>WARNING</level>
  <class>Tester</class>
  <method>main</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>This is a warning message</message>
 </record>
</log>
```

There are lots of things I don't want. Is there any way I can control what data be inserted in the xml ? At some point I only want to see my *string* messages.

Comment: Why do you only want to be able to see the messages, the point of a log is to see the conditions it was running under, when something happened.

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need to store your logs as xml? To get them as plain text try this:

```
fHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
```

Also you can [implement your own formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the build in [`XMLFormatter.format()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/logging/XMLFormatter.java#XMLFormatter.format%28java.util.logging.LogRecord%29) method pretty much hard-codes XML format. If you need a different one, you can implement your own formatter (similar to `XMLFormatter`) and use it explicitly:

```
fHandler.setFormatter(new MyXMLFormatter());
```